# C++ Seekp() in binary files is removing the data

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to use seekp() function with binary files to modify the data of certain integer. I have made simple test program to test seekp funstion but it does not work rather it deletes the old content in file.

```
// position in output stream
#include <fstream>      // std::ofstream
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::ofstream outfile{"test.dat" ,std::ios::binary| std::ios::out};
    struct t {
        int x;
        
    };
    t t1{ 36};
    t t2{ 2 };
    t t3{ 3 };
    
    outfile.seekp(4 , std::ios::beg );
    outfile.write((char*)&t1 , sizeof(t1));
    outfile.write((char*)&t2, sizeof(t2));
    outfile.write((char*)&t3, sizeof(t3));
    

    outfile.close();

    std::ifstream iutfile{ "test.dat" ,std::ios::binary  };
    t read;
    while (iutfile.read((char*)&read, sizeof(read)))
    {
        std::cout << "\n\n\t" << read.x;
    }
    iutfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**#here are my steps i am doing to test it:#**
1)comment the outfile.seekp(4 , std::ios::beg );  in code above then it will print the contents in file
2)now uncomment the seekp line and comment the two outfile.write() lines leaving one to test whetehr seekp is putting the pointer so i can write at exact loaction But when i do this the previous data lost
3)i then tried commenting all write lines leaving seekp lines uncommented and then i saw the whole file cintent is removed

WHat i am doing wrong i cant understand .  I have tried seekp(sizeof(int) , std::ios::beg) but it also doest not work ..    Any help please

Comment: The problem is the lone `std::ios::out` flag when opening the file. It truncates the file, i.e. removes all earlier contents. Please refer to your text-books which should have information about this.

Comment: i cant understand. Will you please tell me what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: When you use only `std::ios::out` as the open-mode (regardless of the `binary` flag) you say you want to open a brand new file for writing. If the file exists, then its contents is erased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You destroy content of file every time you open it, it has nothing to do with `seekp`.

`std::ios::out` means implicitly `std::ios::trunc`, unless there is `std::ios::in` or `std::ios::app` as well (yes, it's a mess). See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) for detailed description of how flags work with each other.

You need to open file in append mode and then `seekp` to position that interests you:

```
std::ofstream outfile{"test.dat" ,std::ios::binary | std::ios::app}; //out is optional 
std::ofstream outfile{"test.dat" ,std::ios::binary | std::ios::app | std::ios::out};
```

Comment: i have tried it but it is writing content to the end of file instead of replacing the values at seekp postiton

Comment: Now i have tried std::ofstream outfile{"test.dat" ,std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out}; instead of std::ofstream outfile{"test.dat" ,std::ios::binary | std::ios::app | std::ios::out}; This works for me. Thanks for help man